# Check cell value, copy when matching

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

I have a constantly growing list.

If a certain cell value is greater than 10, the whole row should be copied into a certain worksheet.
If the value is 10 or smaller, the next row should be checked, until the last row containing data is reached.

This is my current macro. It copies the rows to the same locations like before. I need them to be listed without free space.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Set s1 = Sheets("Hours")
Set s2 = Sheets("Check")
N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
j = 1
For i = 1 To N
    If s1.Cells(i, "R").Value > "10" Then
       s1.Cells(i, "R").EntireRow.Copy s2.Cells(j, 1)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: record yourself doing a filter instead.

Comment: in your post you wrote you want to copy the row if `cell.value > 10`. However, in your code you are doing the copying at the `Else` , when `cell.value <= 10` , so which one is it suppose to be ?

Comment: @Shai-Rado thank you, I got that wrong, i corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried not to move away from your original code (even though using `AutoFilter` method was quite Tempting)

I think your error was due to not fully qualify the way you are looking for `N` (last row); You used `N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row`, and if the `ActiveSheet` is another sheet then you would get a different value for `Rows.Count`. I just added the worksheet reference `N = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row`

I added another "safety" criteria, in case you have a text in column "R", I've modifed your `If` criteria to 'If IsNumeric(s1.Range("R" & i)) And s1.Range("R" & i).Value > 10 Then`

**Code**

```
Sub Copy()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set s1 = Sheets("Hours")
Set s2 = Sheets("Check")

N = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
j = 1
For i = 1 To N
    If IsNumeric(s1.Range("R" & i)) And s1.Range("R" & i).Value > 10 Then
        s1.Cells(i, "R").EntireRow.Copy s2.Cells(j, 1)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!
Actually the problem you mentioned before almost solved my problem, but this one is even better!

Comment: you could use `With s1` to shorten and simplify your code even more if you wanted

Comment: Just stumbled over another problem:

Is it possible to let the script start "scanning" from row 10 and not from the very first?

Comment: I thought maybe be like adding i+10 in the loop but that wont help :/

Comment: Well, actually it was more than simple :D

For i = 10

Comment: @edorius  exactly, don't be afraid to try new stuff, VBA is fun

Answer (score 1):

You can do a post-process when finished the current script, deleting the empty rows (change the range "C50" to the max range of column/row to check empty):

```
  dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
  Set r = Sheets("Check").Range("A1:C5000")
  rows = r.rows.Count
  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
  Next
```